# I cannot compare two strings in PHP

Tags: php, string, comparison-operators

```
    <?php
    $gender = "devilcode";
    if (($gender == "female") || ($gender = "male"))
        {
            echo "ok";
        }
    else echo "no";
    ?>
```

It should output "no" but it outputs "ok". What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Put double equals for $man condition as everybody says. And also put OR instead of ||. Maybe it changes something. And also no need to parentheses for conditions. It should work.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are assigning `$gender` to be male, rather than testing it for comparison, you need two equal signs:

```
$gender = "devilcode";
if (($gender == "female") || ($gender == "male"))
    echo "ok";
else 
    echo "no";
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be the other way round? Assigning one equal sign and comparison two equal signs?

Answer (score 7):

You're missing an equals sign:

```
($gender == "male")
```

Edit: For this very reason, many coders suggest writing the comparison the other way around, with the static value on the left:

```
if ("male" == $gender) { ... }
```

This way, if you forget and use = instead of ==, you get a syntax error.

Answer (score 5):

Is the second part of the IF `$gender="male"`? I think this is returning true always and is causing the problem. Make it `$gender=="male"`

Answer (score 2):

there is a bug in the second part of your test. replace

```
($gender = "male") // assign $gender with the value "male"
                   // this is always evaluated to TRUE in your test
```

by

```
($gender == "male") // test that $gender is equal to "male"
```

Answer (score 1):

Good practice for writing conditions, which protects from errors like this is using inverse notation:

```
if ('female' === $gender || 'male' === $gender) {...
```

or:

```
$allowed = array('male', 'female', 'unknown');
if (in_array($gender, $allowed)) {...
```

Answer (score 1):

You are assigning the var `$gender` to 'male' (`$gender = 'male'`) instead of copmaring it (`$gender == 'male'`)

Also if you want to test against several possible outcomes try `in_array()`

```
$gender = 'devilcode'
$genders = array('female','male','unknown')
if(in_array($gender, $genders)){
 echo 'ok';
}else{
 echo 'no';
}
```

Regards.